# How can I use Jenkins to SSH into an EC2 Instance with a private key pem file which is password protected

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, amazon-ec2

My aim is to execute shell commands on an EC2 instance as part of Jenkins job.

So I'm trying to SSH into an EC2 Instance with a private key pem file which is password protected from Jenkins build job, what are the ideal ways to do that?

Comment: check out https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin. it supports passphrases on your ssh keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by burnettk, the plugin: [Publish Over SSH](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) was helpful in my scenario. I was trying to "ADD SSH Host" in Configure Section of Jenkins but got fed up with "unable to connect" message and tried Publish over SSH plugin it helped out.

Comment: If we want to ssh into two different EC2 instances with two different .pem files then what we can do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Login to jenkins

Create a "New item" or in your existing jenkins job do following

Goto "General" tab

Now under "Build>Execute shell>command"

write your command to ssh to the EC2 instance

ssh ec2-user@ 'bash -s' < script.sh

Is this helpful!!

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution it works for one time, but then it will show 'failed'  Are you still here available?